# Xamarin FlexLayout inside FlexLayout not sizing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to use a FlexLayout inside a FlexLayout. The first one is for wrapping columns on the page. The inside one is for wrapping words on a row. If I use a FlexLayout inside a StackLayout I get the following:

[image]

This is a great result already but as you can see the text is flowing off of the page. I've used a Scrollview to be able to scroll down which work perfectly also. I would however like the columns to wrap to the next column on the right. My thoughts were to add FlexLayout inside the FlexLayout but that's where the trouble began. Here's (part of) the code I use to generate the result above.

This is the TabDetailsPage. It binds on the 'Xaml' property in the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Padding="0"
             x:Class="eTabber.Views.TabDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding PageTitle}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <StyleSheet Source="css\TabDetailsPage.css" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout
        StyleClass="MainContainer"
        Spacing="0"
        Margin="0"
        Padding="0">
        <ScrollView Margin="0" Padding="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <ContentView Content="{Binding Xaml}" />
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the C# code:

```
    public BindableObject Xaml
    {
        get
        {
            var column = new StackLayout()
            {
                StyleClass= new List<string> { "ColumnContainer" }
            };

            foreach (var line in Doc.Lines)
            {
                var row = new FlexLayout
                {
                    StyleClass = new List<string> { "RowContainer" }
                };

                column.Children.Add(row);

                InterpretDirective(row, line);
            }

            return column;
        }
    }
```

This is the stylesheet used:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.MainContainer {
}

.ColumnContainer {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.RowContainer {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    align-items: start;
    /* ---- */
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.WordContainer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.LabelContainer {
}
```

If I exchange the StackLayout with a FlexLayout I get an empty page. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this may be a bug in Xamarin. Lot's of posts on several forums about this and no solution so far.

Comment: Hi , do you mean this line code `var column = new StackLayout()` exchange with a `FlexLayout` get an empty page ?

Comment: Yes, exactly that line. What I see is that the Height and Width of the inner FlexLayout stays at -1.

Comment: Maybe you wrapping too much layout in Xaml , you can have a try with [Selecting direct child elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/#selecting-direct-child-elements) to set css style . Selectors can be combined without limitation, such as `StackLayout>ContentView>label.email`.If you can share the sample project link here , I will check it in my local site .

Comment: Filed a bug on GitHub here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9537